# AngularJS promises are not invoking `then` callback when completed

Tags: angularjs, promise, q

I have something like a master controller that sets some stuff in the scope, so the inner controllers can use it.

That setup work is asynchronous, so I've wrapped it in a promise, but it's not executing it's callback unless it was already resolved (I tried setting a breakpoint, and if I wait enough, it actually runs the `then` callback).

Here's a fiddle that reproduces my problem with a timeout rather than a network request: http://jsfiddle.net/LMv8v/1/

### HTML

```
<div ng-app>
    <div ng-controller="configController">
        <div ng-controller="testC">
            {{test}}
            {{foo}}
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

### Javascript

```
function configController ($scope, $q) {
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    $scope.config = deferred.promise;

    setTimeout(function() {
        console.log('timeout');
        deferred.resolve({
            'foo' : 'baz'
        });
    }, 1000);
};

function testC($scope) {
    $scope.test = 'I am working, uh?';
    $scope.config.then(function(config) {
        console.log('then...');
        $scope.$apply(function() {
            $scope.foo = config.foo;
        });
    });
};
```

It shows the '*timeout*', but not the '*then...*' message.

(I know that this would be better suited for a Service, but I already have plenty of code with the nested scopes and I want to get it working before I start refactoring)

Comment: Are you using `$http`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using `$.getJSON()` (from jQuery I am guessing)

You will run into a similar issue where you are resolving something outside of the Angular world, try the following.

```
$.getJSON('ajax/test.json', function(data) {
   $scope.$apply(function(){
      deferred.resolve({
            'foo' : 'baz'
      });
  });
});
```

**[Example on jsfiddle with jQuery ajax](http://jsfiddle.net/markcoleman/LMv8v/5/)**

Comment: that makes the example work, but does not solve my problem yet :/ I cannot replace `setTimeout` with `$timeout` because my real code is doing a json request.

Comment: and I was already using `$apply`, the problem is that the `fulfilled` callback is not being invoked somehow :(

Comment: bah!, I missed the network request part, so I assume you are using `$http`?

Comment: yeah, otherwise I would not even bother with timeouts :p

Comment: awesome, it worked now! :D I thought that the promises `resolve/then` would work seamlessly without needing to wrap in an `$apply`... Thanks!!